# output a range and use it in a sumproduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I am trying to do the following:

Enter three, then let excel use sumproduct on those three columns

For example, if I enter the number 1,2,3, then the formula is like sumproduct(column A,column B, column C)

I have tried vlookup, if-else and some random junk, but could not find the solution.

Sample data:

input   56

```
1      2       3        4       5
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
1000    1000    1000    1000    1000
```

Comment: no formula will "do" anything... what you expect, is to have your calculator wash the dishes... please *rethink* what you really need... wouldn't ctrl+F do the job? it will find whatever you like (if it is anywhere)... and to select the column manually afterwards shouldn't be the big deal if the prper cell is already highlighted ;)

Comment: But this work requires too many iterations of such task, and the spreadsheet may be larger later. Will naming the range do the trick?

Comment: show some test data and expected output.

Comment: Ugh, I do not know how to format the input so that it will display "input: 56" at the top, and 1, 2, 56, 4, 5 as column heads, and the 1000's are all in the column.

Comment: so you would want the entire column in the same order?  It can be done in a INDEX/MATCH formula, but I would suggest vba as it will be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this formula:

```
=INDEX($A:$E,ROW(),MATCH($I$1,$1:$1,0))
```

Where I1 was the input.

INDEX allows for three parameters.  `INDEX(range,row,column)`

So we set the range for all of columns A through E.  Then the ROW() returns the row number in which the formula is.

The MATCH() finds the column that has the input from I1 in row 1 and returns that relative column number.

[image]

Just realized you wanted the sum of the numbers in that column.  Use this to do that:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:E,2,MATCH($I$1,1:1,0)):INDEX(A:E,MATCH(1E+99,INDEX(A:E,0,MATCH($I$1,1:1,0))),MATCH($I$1,1:1,0)))
```

It will dynamically find the range of number from row 2 to the end of the numbers in the column that is returned to have the criteria in I1 in row 1:1.

Comment: It is a bit above my head... Still parsing the formula. Could you give a hint?

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: @user101998 add the sum in one formula.  I missed the title.